# Compactness assumptuion in Riesz_Markov representation theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ a compact metric space; I have to identify the dual of the set of continuous functions on $X$, $C(X)^*$. 
By Riesz representation theorem we have that it can be identified with the space of regular Radon measures, normed by total variation(see for instance Dunford, N.; Schwartz, J.T. (1958), Linear operators, Part I).

> **question:** What happens if I remove the compactness of $X$?

Comment: I think you can reduce it to $X$ being a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: But in this case is still true that the dual $C(X)^*$ is the space of Raodn measures? Or is it larger?

Comment: Hmm, see Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Chapter 2. That should have a lot of details. And I remember that if you allow non-compact spaces $X$, you have to replace $C(X)$ with $C_c(X)$, the continuous functions on $X$ with compact support.

Comment: $C(X)$ is not a normed space then. Do you consider some non-normed topology on it, if so, which one? Or do you consider the space of bounded continuous functions? Or of functions vanishing at infinity? Or of functions with compact support? The answers are all different. Something can be said about linear functionals in each case: and something *was* already said: on Wikipedia and [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89274/) in particular.